# Compass generated sprites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass, sass

i am trying to convert the background images currently being used within my navigation to a sprite to save on http requests, though im getting the following error

```
 content: "\000a Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'navigation-sprite'.\000a   (in \002f home\002f html\002f teammngt\002f app\002f assets\002f stylesheets\002f navigation.css.scss)";
```

scss file

```
@import "compass";
```

`@import "navigation/main/*.png";`

```
a {
  display: table-cell;
  /* #header_main height + 1, to move it 1px into the header_main strip */
  height: 61px;
  width: 120px;
  @include navigation-sprite(bg-normal);
  //background: url('navigation/main/bg-normal.png') no-repeat;
  /* Concerning fonts/text */
  line-height: 26px;
  /* Concerning text align */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
```

for sure im doing something wrong here, but im not having much luck working it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@import "compass";
@import "navigation/main/*.png";
@include all-main-sprites;
```

use like this:

```
@include main-sprite(bg-normal);
```

Comment: adding that line i now get `content: "\000a Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'all-navigation-sprites'.\000a   (in \002f home\002f html\002f teammngt\002f app\002f assets\002f stylesheets\002f navigation.css.scss)";`

Comment: that code worked in dev, but when i loaded into production i got the following error `content: "\000a Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.\000a Load path: \002f home\002f html\002f teammngt\000a   (in \002f home\002f html\002f teammngt\002f app\002f assets\002f stylesheets\002f navigation.css.scss)";`